# Mysterious KeyError

Tags: python

I'm studying for my CS test right now and trying to write code to, given the entire IMDB database in plaintext, find the actors with the most films in common. I'm pretty much done, I just keep hitting a strange KeyError. Here's my code:

[image]

The problem I am encountering is, when I run it, it produces a keyerror when it runs the highlighted code. I have verified that it is indeed indexing a dictionary with a string and that said key is in the dictionary but it still isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: please copy and paste your code instead of an image so we can actually do stuff with it.

Comment: We all jumped all over this one and made the same statements multiple times :)

Comment: Don't use *dict* as a variable name - *dict* is a reserved Python word and you may accidentally override built-in functions. Most probably it will work, but you'll never know when it bites you in the ass.

Answer (score 8):

When you do `other_people = people_and_their_movies`, you're not making a copy.  You're making `other_people` point to the same object that `people_and_their_movies` points to.  So when you do `del other_people[actor1]`, you delete the actor from *both* dicts (because they are the same).

Instead, do `other_people = people_and_their_movies.copy()`.

(Incidentally, on StackOverflow it's better to copy and paste your actual code as text instead of a screenshot.  This way people can cut and paste your code and try it out themselves to figure out what's wrong with it.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I tried to copy the code but my formatting kept messing up. I couldn't figure out how to paste multiple lines of code and have it properly formatted keeping the right indentation.

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies within this line of code:

```
other_people = people_and_their_movies
```

This is not creating a duplicate copy of the dictionary. Instead, both of these variables are pointing to the same dictionary in memory.  Thus, when you execute this line:

```
del other_people[actor1]
```

You are deleting actor1 from the same dictionary that people_and_their_movies points to.

You could try this:

```
other_people = people_and_their_movies.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier you assign

```
other_people = people_and_their_movies
```

so when you

```
del other_people[actor1]
```

you're actually deleting that key from both dicts.  `other_people` and `people_and_their_movies` point to the same object at this point.

Check out python's [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module for a way to make a true copy of your dict, so you can safely decouple them and delete from only one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Use *itertools.combinations()* - and you won't have to delete actors, and you'll be able to use only one loop:

```
for actor1, actor2 in itertools.combinations(people_and_their_movies,2):
    <whatever you want to do>
```